# Virtual Memory,Page size,Maximum Virtual Address

Tags: operating-system

In a paging system a virtual address consists of 24 bits, in which 16 bits are displacement and 8 bits for page number.

Calculate :

1. Page size
2. Maximum number of pages
3. Maximum virtual address space

Comment: Great, do it. What's the problem?

Comment: Well the the whole question is the problem, and I want it solved. Would you mind?

Comment: All three sub-questions have the form "compute some power of two", literally just put it in a calculator.

Comment: @harold 'literally just put it in a calculator.' will just not do as a copypasta homework answer!

Comment: @harold I'm confused on how to go about solving this, I think i'm not getting it right... would you mind solving it so i can compare it with my solution

Comment: I've got a better idea; why not show your solution and indicate where you have an issue with it?

Comment: 16 bits are reserved for displacement, so the page size is 2^16 = 64KB
8 bits are reserved for page number, so each segment can contain 2^8= 256 pages

Comment: but maximum virtual address?

Comment: 'In a paging system a virtual address consists of 24 bits'.  Anyway, why not ask your prof/TA instead of posting your homework here?   One of your fellow students ratted this out as an assignment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37502008/758133

Comment: got it maximum virtual address space=256*64K=16384K=16M
...
thanks for your help @MartinJames

Answer (score 1):

(1) 16 bits are reserved for displacement, so the page size is 2^16 = 64 KB

(2) 8 bits are reserved for page number, so each segment can contain 2^8= 256 pages

(3) maximum virtual address space=256*64KB=16384KB=16MB