# Non-Preemptive multitasking Scheduling Algorithm

Tags: operating-system, multitasking, preemptive

What causes transition of process from one state to another state if non-preemptive multitasking scheme is being used to manage multiple tasks in the system?

Comment: If you have problems with homework, your first stop should be your teacher/prof/TA, not SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose a process is in running state. Now it moves to waiting state for I/O. In that case, another ready process will be context switched and  will be executed.

Comment: can you elaborate it further.

Comment: @Ibrahim : So, nonpreemptive just means that if a process is getting executed , then other process will have to wait whether they have a shorter job, high priority or anything. But suppose a process is running and it has to take some I/O. So, it will be shifted to device queue and in the meantime there is no process which is getting executed and hence we can take one ready queue and execute it.

Comment: No problem bro! :) Happy to help :)

Comment: :)
i want a more little help.....i got stuck in solving a problem....can you tell me how to get
Page size, Maximum number of pages, Maximum virtual address space
for a paging system a virtual address consists of 24 bits, in which 16 bits are displacement and 8 bits for page number.
and i also want to know what is displacement in this problem?

Comment: @Ibrahim : I think it would be good enough to create a new post for this problem as it is not related to the one we have discussed

Comment: @MartinJames : You are rude, I must say. And there is no point of downvoting an answer just because it answers a conceptual homework question.

Comment: @PriyanshGoel would you consider the gross homework question dumps on this tag, conceptual or otherwise, as 'rude' too, or abuse of SO contributors, or disrespect of other students who actually do some work, or something else?